# Update product quantity and warning user they have exceeded quantity

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a shopping cart with empty cart, update cart and delete item buttons. I would like to inform users of the quantity of each stock item and advise them if they are trying to order a quantity of an item that is in excess of stock quantity. Also I would like to update the stock quantity each time an order is processed. This is what I have currently. Appreciate any help anyone can offer on this.

```
<?php

    include("includes/db.php");
    include("includes/functions.php");

    if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='delete' && $_REQUEST['pid']>0){
        remove_product($_REQUEST['pid']);
    }
    else if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='clear'){
        unset($_SESSION['cart']);
    }
    else if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='update'){
        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
            $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
            $q=intval($_REQUEST['product'.$pid]);
            if($q>0 && $q<=999){
                $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty']=$q;
            }
            else{
                $msg='Some proudcts not updated!, quantity must be a number between 1 and 999';
            }
        }
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Shopping Cart</title>
<script language="javascript">
    function del(pid){
        if(confirm('Do you really mean to delete this item')){
            document.form1.pid.value=pid;
            document.form1.command.value='delete';
            document.form1.submit();
        }
    }
    function clear_cart(){
        if(confirm('This will empty your shopping cart, continue?')){
            document.form1.command.value='clear';
            document.form1.submit();
        }
    }
    function update_cart(){
        document.form1.command.value='update';
        document.form1.submit();
    }


</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form1" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="pid" />
<input type="hidden" name="command" />
    <div style="margin:0px auto; width:600px;" >
    <div style="padding-bottom:10px">
        <h1 align="center">Your Shopping Cart</h1>
    <input type="button" value="Continue Shopping" onclick="window.location='products.php'" />
    </div>
      <div style="color:#F00"><?php  if (isset($msg)) {echo $msg;} ?></div>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="1px" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:11px; background-color:#E1E1E1" width="100%">
        <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) && is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
                echo '<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-weight:bold"><td>Serial</td><td>Name</td><td>Price</td><td>Qty</td><td>Amount</td><td>Options</td></tr>';
                $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
                for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
                    $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
                    $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
                    $pname=get_product_name($pid);
                    if($q==0) continue;
            ?>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td><?php echo $i+1?></td><td><?php echo $pname?></td>
                    <td><big style="color:green">€</big><?php echo get_price($pid)?></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product<?php echo $pid?>" value="<?php echo $q?>" maxlength="3" size="2" /></td>                    
                    <td><big style="color:green">€</big><?php echo get_price($pid)*$q?></td>
                  <td><a href="javascript:del(<?php echo $pid?>)">Remove</a></td></tr>
          <?php                 
                }
            ?>
              <tr bgcolor="#BADAEF"><td><b>Order Total: <big style="color:green">€</big><?php echo get_order_total()?></b></td><td colspan="5" align="right"><input type="button" value="Empty Cart" onclick="clear_cart()"><input type="button" value="Update Cart" onclick="update_cart()"><input type="button" value="Continue to Place Order" onclick="window.location='billing.php'"></td></tr>
          <?php
            }
            else{
                echo "<tr bgColor='#FFFFFF'><td>There are no items in your shopping cart!</td>";
            }
        ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please show the screenshot of the view when you run the above code ?

Comment: Unfortunately it won't let me says I need 10 rep

Comment: okay :) Your question is not very clear how and where you want us to help you. Please explain the exact problem you are facing when coding for `informing users of the quantity of each stock item and advise them if they are trying to order a quantity of an item that is in excess of stock quantity.` What I normally would do is, on click of the update button, SUM the total number of a particular product and check in the database if it is available and then process based on the return.